# My quicksort crashes on already sorted data

Tags: crash, quicksort

I wanted to check the performance time for different data in array (random, already sorted, sorted in descending order).

```
void Quicksort(int *T, int Lo, int Hi)
{
  if (Lo<Hi){
      int x=T[Lo];
      int i=Lo, j=Hi;
   do
   {
      while (T[i] < x) ++i;
      while (T[j] > x) --j;
      if (i<=j)
      {
         int tmp = T[i];
         T[i] = T[j];
         T[j] = tmp;
         ++i; --j;
      }
   } while(i < j);
   if (Lo < j) Quicksort(T, Lo, j);
   if (Hi > i) Quicksort(T, i, Hi);
  }
}
```

Here are the functions used to generate and fill the testing array:

```
int* createArr(int length){
    int* Arr= new int[length];
    return Arr;
    }

void Random(int *A, int length){
        for (int i=0;i<length;i++){ 
        A[i]=rand();
    }
}
void Order(int *A, int length){
        for (int i=0;i<length;i++){ 
        A[i]=i;
    }
}

void Backwards(int *A, int length){
        for (int i=0;i<length;i++){ 
        A[i]=length-i;
    }
}
```

It works fine for random numbers, but when I try to fill it in ascending order and sort, it crashes with stack overflow. Can anyone give me a hint of why is it happening?

Comment: Looks like ordered desc array is the worst case for this algorithm and you are probably running it on very large array so your function calls itself so many times that you are running into stack overflow. Check your OS and compiler documentation on what are the limits of call stack. To defeat this issue you may consider to replace recursion with loops.

Comment: @AlexanderM The ordered desc array is actually the worst case for the algorithm which chooses the first (or last) item as a pivot. Selecting the central item works better on average - it is not very likely to often find the smallest or largest item at the array's center. Even better is probing three positions and choosing the median of the three as a pivot.

Answer (score 0):

When you choose the [Lo] item as a partioning value (a pivot), and the array is already sorted, then you get a partitioning 1 to (length–1). This causes the next (recursive) call on a longer part of the array to handle just one item less then the previous level. So, as @AlexanderM noted, you will get as deep into the recursion as the length of your array. If the array is big, it will almost certainly cause the stack overflow.

Try using a tail reursion: check which part is shorter and sort it with a resursive call, then continue on the current level with the longer part. To do that replace the very first `if` with `while` and replace

```
if (Lo < j) Quicksort(T, Lo, j);
if (Hi > i) Quicksort(T, i, Hi);
```

with

```
if (j-Lo < Hi-i)
{
    Quicksort(T, Lo, j);
    Lo = i;
}
else
{
    Quicksort(T, i, Hi);
    Hi = j;
}
```

This won't make the program any faster – it will still need O(n^2) time on an already-sorted array, but will protect against linear stack memory usage, keeping it at worst O(log n).

For further directions concerning better performance see Wikipedia article [Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), part **Choice of pivot**.